# TensorflowOnSpark returning hdfs scheme not implemented

Tags: hadoop, tensorflow, pyspark, hdfs

I just setup the tensorflowOnSpark API on my server machine and am running the sample mnist examples that come with the library. Running the simple RDD with Spark works perfectly fine, but when I run the TF records example, I get the error:

```
UnimplementedError: File system scheme hdfs not implemented
```

as per https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/hadoop i have set all the env variables but no luck. The program fails at:

```
files = tf.gfile.Glob("hdfs://namenode/user/user-name/mnist/tfr/train/part-*")
```

it is not able to identify hdfs as a scheme. i saw a similar question here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4480 but that doesn't work either. Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: It sounds like TensorFlow was not compiled with HDFS support. I don't have a Hadoop setup, but I can get past that check (the [first one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/env.cc#L191)) and to HDFS-specific code on the Docker image (e.g. `docker run -it  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0 python`).

Comment: Well I installed tensorflow from anaconda, and I don't think anaconda allows to configure the installation with HDFS support, does it? Would I have to go the bazel route and configure?

Comment: Oh, which operating system? It seems to be compiled in by default on Linux pip packages.

Comment: Yes Linux. So doing it via pip install should allow me to configure hadoop support?

Comment: Yep, I just downloaded the CPU Python 3.4 TensorFlow 1.1.0 pip package and it seems to have HDFS support.

Comment: Was able to install tensorflow via pip, but got the below error
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)

My machine only facilitates up until v 3.4.13 and I'm bound with that. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Probably best to build from source in that case. Even if you're not on CentOS, this is probably relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1426